# create a custom rule in visual studio before build the project

Tags: c#, .net, oop

ı have a problem. ı'm new to C# and .Net platform. I have a .Net Framework project. ı want to create a costume class. this class has a properties. when ı want created a instance and use of this class in my project   ı must useable to 1 different way.

1. after using this class run a end method

Myclass cls = new Myclass()

// Some Operations

cls.MyEndMethod();

if i didnt use MyEndMethod() I want the visual studio getting a error and project didnt build .

visual studio has o costume rule for this operation.  this rule name is CA2000.

but my costume class doesnt have a disposible method and or didnt have ı impalementet Idisposible interface.

ı want if anyone create a instance of my class in project he must to use MyEndPointMethod(). because this class going to using dll on project.

Comment: Creating a Visual Studio rule for that wouldn't work well, because people who use your code don't have to use VS; they might be using any other IDE, code editor, or a plain notepad. Why not call the method in the constructor instead?

Comment: thanks for giving advice sir. but my project friend  use same visual studio method. and ı want to it because ı am curious. are you have a idea for this method ?